# My transparent texture images are look black in my Metal render

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I am using following pipelineDescriptor and shader fragments.

I encountered a problem which I could not find solution for.

My textures images fit fine looks great except transparent ones.

Transparent parts (Alpha = 0) of my images looks black on device screen instead of
transparent.

Also, **depthStencilDescriptor.isDepthWriteEnabled = true
depthStencilDescriptor.depthCompareFunction = .less**

```
func buildPipelineState(device: MTLDevice) -> MTLRenderPipelineState {
    
    let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary()
    let vertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: vertexFunctionName)
    let fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: fragmentFunctionName)
    
    let renderPipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
    
  
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
    
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusBlendAlpha
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
    renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
    
    renderPipelineDescriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = .depth32Float
   
    renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
    renderPipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
    renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptor
    
    var renderPipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState! = nil
    
    do {
        
        renderPipelineState = try device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: renderPipelineDescriptor)
        
    } catch let error as NSError {
        
        Swift.print("\(error)")
    }
    
   return renderPipelineState
    
}



fragment half4 basic_fragment_function(VertexOut vIn [[ stage_in ]],
                                    constant Light &light [[ buffer(1) ]]){

  float4 color = vIn.color;

  return half4(color);

}



 fragment half4 textured_fragment_function(VertexOut vIn [[ stage_in ]],
                                    constant Light &light [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                    sampler sampler2d [[ sampler(0) ]],
                                    texture2d<float> texture [[ texture(0) ]]){

  float4 color = texture.sample(sampler2d, vIn.textCoors);

  return half4(color);

}
```

PS;

After I asked this question I used the same image to texture my cube's other sides as well.

On the default side (looking down from z axis)  of the cube transparent parts looks black and you can not see other sides.

But when I change camera location ( rotating cube ) I noticed
that you could see other faces thought image's transparent parts.

I played with
**commandEncoder?.setFrontFacing(.counterClockwise)
commandEncoder?.setCullMode(.none)**

without any luck till now.

Comment: Are you setting `isOpaque` on your `CAMetalLayer` to false?

Comment: I would check the blend ops then. Is it more transparent with 0.75 alpha or 0.25 alpha?

Comment: I discovered something I made a cube with the same image the same image looks transparent at other sides of cube.